# Moving /etc to separate partition

Tags: partition, fstab, etc

How to put `/etc` on separate partition? Obviously i can't do that by editing `/etc/fstab` like i did with `/home`, because... it's in `/etc`. I want `/etc` and `/home` on one partition (sda7), and the rest on the other (sda6). I guess `/etc` must be symlink to `/mnt/part2/etc` (`/mnt/part2` being mount point of sda7), and same with `/home`. But how to tell the system to mount part2 without access to `fstab`?

I'm using Arch Linux x64, if that helps.

Comment: You must `make` your own kernel patched in way that it will automount your `etc` before `init`. Or you could make minimal `bin dev etc lib proc` sysdisk with minimal libraries / utilities (`sh`, `mount` and few libs). Will easily fit under 1MB... btw. this is somewhat same as asking about _how to build house without walls, you can do that but it is mostly useless and it will be hard to add walls afterwards._

Comment: I just learned that it's pretty much undoable. But not because of Linux - because of systemd. Gonna get back to this when I'll have full week free for switching from systemd to something else. Thank you all guys for your support.

And inb4: you say it's pointless. I say, maybe, but this is the reason I have Linux in the first place - to have fun while messing with it!

Comment: use lvm and don't put `/etc` on a different partition

Comment: But more seriously, dude, don't try this unless you really, really, *really* know what you're doing because one mistake will likely render your system unbootable. More to the point, /etc will *rarely* exceed a couple dozen megabytes at most unless you're doing something incredibly stupid elsewhere down the line, so it literally fits into a hollow tooth. Keep it with `/` like absolutely everyone does.

Comment: @Xirdus Again,the same thing we said about writing a kernel patch would also apply to `systemd` -- and it *still* is a bad idea.

Answer (score 11):

One of the first things a linux system is doing is mounting all file systems to the correct mountpoint in order to let all other parts of the system find their files.

The root file system is usually given on the kernel command line. It will mount this file system and look in /etc/fstab for all the other mount points.

If you really want to do anything weird before this happens you can use the [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) for those kind of setup.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is you don't. `/etc` is where all the configuration stuff is: how can the system operate if it doesn't know where to find its configuration?
Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: This is right. Any directory that must exist at the early stages of boot must be part of `/`.

Answer (score 7):

> I want /etc and /home on one partition

No you don't. It's like asking to have your brain transplanted to your knee :-) Whatever your problem is, making `/etc` a separate partition or merging it with `/home` is not the solution. What is the *actual problem you want to solve*?

Comment: +1 for asking the important question of what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know about the original poster, but I am interested in this because just as I can share my home folder and ~/.config among linux installations, I was wondering if I could share /etc the same way and that way installing distros / upgrading would be even more easy and require less reconfiguration.

Comment: @Wizek Since `/etc` contains a lot of host-specific configuration (e.g. /etc/fstab) that is something you really can't easily share across systems. Anything that has a nodename in it is host-specific and would need special treatment.

Comment: That makes sense. But doesn't `/etc` contain at least some configurations that are host-independent? And might make sense to share between hosts? As a ballpark, what would you say the percentage is? 99% host specific? Or perhaps 80%, 50%, 20% or 1% host-specific?

Comment: @Wizek Yes, but sharing at the mount point level is far too coarse. If I'd contemplate sharing `/etc` I'd do it at the file level (i.e. using git, mercurial, rsync, or even Makefiles with a "scp" target.) That's pretty much what Sun's YP (Yellow Pages) did in the olden days. Also consider failure scenarios such as `/etc` not being mountable; then you just made a large number of systems unusable.

Comment: For what it's worth ... Google brought me here because I'm trying to make an immutable core, with mutable config. Some of etc never changes - eg fstab change wont happen without a major event such as adding new storage (very rare, can redo the immutable) - but eg httpd changes are every month or few months.

Comment: For readonly `/`, and writable `/etc` you can possibly use an overlay fs for etc. I've seen it work, but don't know the details of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a straight up answer, but it may help:

The directory `/etc` stores the configuration for your operating system, therefore it should be considered a good idea to have your configuration with your operating system, that is on the same partition. To keep a sensible backup or maybe even share configurations, you could use git:

- create a git repository from your `/etc` and clone/put it to whereever you want to store it
- write an init script which does a `git pull` on "start" to get the most recent version from that special partition into `/etc`
- put the script right after said partition is mounted in your bootup order, somewhere in runlevel S
- have the script do a `git commit` and `git push` on shutdown/reboot to save your current configuration

Two advantages:

1. when something breaks you will always have your configuration where the OS expects it to be
2. you will have versioning and can revert and debig your configurations if you messed up

Comment: This sounds like a poor man's [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/), which is likely to break file permissions and compromise the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible, terrible idea, and I can't honestly think of a single situation where it'd even be desirable.

However, if you *really* want to do this, your best bet would be to write a kernel patch to make it take a second argument similar to `root=/dev/sda1` that lets you specify `etc=/dev/sda2` as well, then have it try to mount `/etc` from there after mounting root and before attempting to execute `init`.

Note that any single mistake at this point would render your entire system unbootable unless you had the sanity to set up a safe fallback `/etc` on the root partition.

Comment: Here's a good reason: Making /etc a separate dataset in a zfs pool allows you to back up /etc independently.

Comment: @FUZxxl And this  is a substantial improvement over, say, `tar -jcvf /backup/etc.tar /etc` how, precisely?

Comment: I do backup with zfs snapshots, sending them over the network with `zfs send`. Having `/etc` on a separate dataset allows me to treat it the same way as all other datasets.