# Moving Application Configurations to Separate Partition

Tags: linux, partition, backup

So by default, most services install their configuration files to `/etc/<application>`. On my *physical* systems, I'm using LVM for volume management, and specifically so I can rollback snapshots when I hose things up.

I've got a lot of custom applications installed from source that allow me to setup where their configurations are installed to and read from, but they're generally pretty willy-nilly by default - they read from `$HOME`, or a specific directory in their source tree, and sometimes `/etc/<application>`.

I was working towards fixing these so that I have them all running with configurations stored in a standard location - this could mean creating `/etc/<app>` myself and keeping them stored in that location (though I'm not sure if that's a bad practice for apps running from src), and it occurred to me that it would be pretty awesome if I could keep them in a subdirectory of `/etc` stored on a completely separate partition/logical volume, then if (for whatever reason) I need to rebuild a server, I can blow away `/root` keep the configuration partition, and just remount it in place, then point the services at the existing configuration files.

I did some quick digging around and found `/etc/local`, which appears to be made for this purpose, but I found several docs saying that I shouldn't be using that myself. That directory doesn't appear to exist on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Moving these to a separate partition/configuration folder would also allow me to back them up easily (I could just point rsync at the root and backup everything with a single command)/cron job).

Besides my "source installed" applications, I was thinking about trying to move my DNS/DHCP/iptables/nginx/apache configurations there as well - i.e. applications that have extensive configurations and need to be backed up, and if I rebuilt the server for whatever reason, I would want those configurations to be retained.

Edit: After looking around a little bit more, it looks like `/usr/local/etc` would be a good location and shouldn't cause any issues having it on a separate partition.

Any recommendations on this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Moving /etc to separate partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/moving-etc-to-separate-partition) for reasons it's difficult (if not impossible) to use separate partitions for `/etc` or subdirectories thereof.

You might find `etckeeper` useful for your use-case; it allows keeping `/etc` in a version-control system such as `git`, which means you can then easily maintain a copy somewhere else with all the history.

If you're going to manage multiple machines though you should really look at centralised configuration management, with tools such as `cfengine`, `puppet`, `chef`, `ansible`...