# Upgraded Fedora 23 won't boot to graphical login - only brings up text terminal

Tags: fedora, boot, upgrade

I upgraded from 22 to 23 with fedup and after updating, cleaning, and rebooting, all I get is the terminal. My older versions, including my rescue, won't boot. Any ideas?

Comment: Fedora is famous for upgrading badly.  The most common way to deal with upgrades of distros is to keep the `/home` (and `/etc` and `/var` on servers) on different partitions from the rest of the system.  If you can copy `/home` to a different partition you can always do a fresh install on one partition and mount `/home` from another partition.

Comment: The title says "won't boot" but the body says "gets [to] the terminal". Does terminal mean bios, grub, or tty1? Maybe you mean it doesn't boot to a graphical login?

Comment: Won't boot to a graphical login. Tty1 is what comes up.

Comment: Anyway to recover with the access I have or do I have to do a full install from a live cd?

Comment: If it's bringing up the terminal, it's booting.

Comment: What `startx` does if you log in at terminal and type `startx` at shell prompt?

Comment: Apparently u just needed to reinstall kde! Got my desktop to come up!

Comment: I think you should post your comment as an answer, so people who meet the same problem could see the solution

Comment: @grochmal I'm obviously a bit biased here, but I think that's unfair. It _seems_ like there's a lot of stories of bad upgrades, but that's because people are much less likely to say anything when an upgrade goes well, and even when they do, it's less interesting or memorable. (There's that thing where [every happy family is the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Karenina_principle).) Anecdotally, since we've switched to fedup and dnf system-upgrade, the process is generally quite reliable. Of course, having separate `/home/` is a nice suggestion, and one should always have backups.

Comment: Also, btw, you _can't_ have `/etc` on a separate partition. Stuff there is needed to boot. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/moving-etc-to-separate-partition

Comment: @mattdm - well, i'm one of those with a failed Fedora upgrade once upon a time.  I'm biased i need to admit, sorry for that.  (it was around Fedora 16 so it is a long time ago).

Answer (score 0):

The [fedup](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp) is obsoleted since `Fedora 22`, the [DNF system upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) should be used to update from `Fedora 22` to `Fedora 23`.

Comment: @CynthiaPeterson lets find out in comments to the question if you could recover without full reinstall

Comment: Thank you serge! I will remember to not use fedup. I got the desktop to finally work after reinstalling kde

Comment: However, the `fedup` command remains and will redirect to DNF system upgrade; there's no harm in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `dnf`plugin system upgrade package, From the terminal type the following command :

```
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade --enablerepo=updates-testing
```

then download the updated packages:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=23 --allowerasing
```

The `--allowerasing` will erase packages which dependencies cannot be satisfied.

As montionned by @Serge `fedup` is depricated , you should use `dnf system-upgrade` command to upgrade your OS:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```