# Is there any way of resizing /etc directory in linux machine

Tags: linux, centos, etc

I have tried to create a partition name "/etc' at OS installation time and my installation was not working.When I cancel creating "/etc" directory than it worked. Though all configuration files are available in /etc directory but I tried to resize. Is there any way of creating a manual "/etc" directory or it is a bad try?

Comment: Why would you want to have `/etc` on its own partition? Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/moving-etc-to-separate-partition

Comment: I have tried to create manual partitions like /tmp ,/usr,/var,/home directories but failed to create /etc directory .Is there any possible answers for this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving /etc to separate partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/moving-etc-to-separate-partition)

Comment: There is no practical reason that I could think of for having `/etc` on a partition by itself. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Actually not for any serious issue,just for experiment.I could not found any information (why I cant manage /etc directory)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it is not useful if you use too many partitions, they significantly decrease the flexibility of your system. Unfortunately, many installer regularly *enforces* the user to fragment his machine into small partitions, what he later finds a nearly impossible task to fix. (In fact it is easy, but you don't need it, simply don't use partitions and so is it.)

For normal home installations it is typically enough if you are using only a single root partition and everything is there.

If you are using, or have to use multiple partitions (volumes), it is far better if you are using some advanced technology for that; for example [LVM](https://wiki.debian.org/LVM) can *move your partitions between hard disks without even unmounting them*.

Your steps to unify your /etc partition to the rest of your system are these:

1. copy everything from the /etc, for example with a `cp -vfa /etc /etc-`
2. umount `/etc`
3. `rmdir /etc`
4. `mv /etc- /etc`